# Как лучше загрузить на сервер сразу много файлов имея ссылки?

Tags: php

Подскажите каким образом лучше сделать загрузку файлов на сервер имея только ссылки на файлы. Если мне надо например 100 файлов размером до 500кб. Каким образом будет их быстрее всего загрузить используя php.

file_put_contents долговато с этим справляется. Есть варианты ?

Comment: По Вашему вопросу совсем непонятно, какой софт работает на сервере. А Вы, скорее всего, говорите (не рассказывая нам этого) о неком ПОДРАЗУМЕВАЕМОМ наборе софта. Например, вы считаете, что на сервере стоит PHP. Может, добавите это в вопрос? и пришпандорите тег? Сразу знатоки придут, а не такие лохи, как я :-)

Comment: Загружайте архив, а не отдельные файлы.

Comment: @КириллМалышев есть только ссылки, нет возможности архивом.

Comment: @S.H. Так я написал php. И тег поставил. Понятно что есть зависимость от системы и от канала и т.д. Но меня интересует более абстрагировано от этих подробностей.

Comment: Прошу прощения, в тот момент, когда я читал Ваш вопрос, тега еще не было

Comment: если только ссылки, то никак иначе, в очередь загнать и загружать